# How to call a function after "Complete page load" and "after all external script execution"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to call a function after "Complete page load" and "after all external script execution"  ?

I tried all 4 below option, but no luck!!!

```
$(document).ready..
$(window).load...
window.onload = ...
$(document).ready(function()...
```

Doing setTimeout works for me, But not sure if this 100% efficient!!!!

```
setTimeout(function(){
//your code here
}, 3000);
```

Please advice and help!!!

Comment: I think your external script should  contain a callback somewhere that will hold your function. These external scripts might be executed when `$(document).ready..`

Comment: Yes, but i dont have any access to update those external script to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been terribly interested with your question and going deep to the `jQuery` source I came up with a mad hack :)
But the key point is that you should put this piece of code at the very beginning, right after you plug `jQuery`:

```
$.statesNum = 0;
$.fn.ready = function ( fn ) {
    $.statesNum++;
    jQuery.ready.promise().done( fn ).then(function () {
        $.statesNum--;
        if ($.statesNum == 0) {
            $(document).trigger("afterReady");
        }
    });

    return this;
};
```

Now whenever you want to execute something after all `.ready` functions are done you can do like this:

```
$(document).on("afterReady", function () {
    alert("Hey, the ready functions are executed");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but what is this "$.statesNum++;" does? can you please explain little your logic..

Comment: @Sandeep The logic is behind the jQuery  promises. I am changing the jQuery ready function implementation, so that when a function passed to it, it would increment a counter and add a callback to function which would decrement the counter and if the counter gets to 0 it would trigger `afterReady` event.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts are loaded and executed in the order they appear in your HTML. If you have simple scripts, just put things you want to run later at the bottom.

However if you have complex scripts that run asynchronously (meaning they run in parallel), then it is impossible to know if they have finished executing without actually looking at what they do. E.g. do they (or can they) trigger an event that you can listen to? Or maybe you can use "promise" patterns.

Comment: Oh, ok ... yes my External scripts are "asynchronously and run in parallel... sorry i am not in Advance in JS, what is "do. E.g. do they (or can they) trigger an event that you can listen to? Or maybe you can use "promise" patterns."

Comment: We really can't tell you the specifics unless you tell us what exactly you are running, because every script is different.